# python anaconda vs system best path policy

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have succesfully installed Anaconda3, version 5.0.1 on my Debian sid desktop. I have a concern, though. The default installation prepends tho the PATH environment variable, in the user's .bashrc file, the directory anaconda3/bin. Thus, for this user, the python version active in any terminal turns out to be Anaconda's python 3.6.4, not the current Debian system default's python 2.7.14.

Should I be concerned, as a normal user, not as root, that this might give some trouble when dealing with some issue/activity outside any anaconda environment?? What are the pro's and con's of having anaconda's path appended or prepended to the PATH variable?

Thanks

Comment: I use anaconda for numerical computing, data analysis etc. works flawlessly. However, when it comes to web development or IoT stuff, I usually comment anaconda out because it is sometimes  easier to use the standard python installation (closer to the server). Had no troubles so far. I do use virtual environments though.

Comment: I've never had a problem. Indeed, using anaconda / conda environments has been an overall improvement in my workflow. Outside of a conda environment, your anaconda distribution python interpreter is just like any other.